# Netbeans Swing: Variables declaration disappeared

Tags: swing, netbeans

Got a question:
Just modified my Swing GUI a bit by resizing some buttons and recompiled...then:

`cannot find symbol symbol: variable MachineStatusLabel` and more of the same for other Objects...

Yep, this is a Label in my GUI, no idea why it cannot be found. The generated code section contains the usual stuff like
`javax.swing.JLabel MachineStatusLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();`
and defines everything. But looking at the `Variables declaration - do not modify`-Section, almost all GUI Objects disappeared! There are only two left:

`// Variables declaration - do not modify

private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;

private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;

// End of variables declaration`

Is there a way to let NetBeans rebuild the whole GUI into this generated code? Somehow the GUI Objects seem to have just been messed up by NetBeans :-( Adding the declarations for the missing Objects manually didn't help either...

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Comment: My recommendation: don't use NetBeans drag and drop gui builder to build the gui, but instead code it by hand. Then you and only you are responsible for the code and its integrity.  I think that except for the most basic GUI's, doing it by hand is actually easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the value of the 'Generate Components as' property in the Options dialog.

The Option appears of the GUI Builder tab of the Miscellaneous category.

Here is the screenshot...

[image]

It sounds like you need to have the property value set as 'Fields in Form Class'.

If you change the option value, you will probably need to make a minor change in your form to trigger a code regeneration, too.